# Regex to match all but hyperlinks for .NET

Tags: .net, regex

Stack!

I am trying to match all text but hyperlinks in .NET. I have found a thread about it, but it is not working for .NET -> [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Exemplifying:

```
Text text 123 123 timi other text http://www.stack.com asd asd sadokaspodkas
```

It should match all but http://www.stack.com.

I am trying to lowercase all text, but hyperlinks.
I dont have a working regex.

THANKS

Comment: Why not to match links and just remove them?

Comment: Well, if I were you, I'd *remove* the hyperlinks, and get the text without them. Try `Regex.Replace(input, @"https?://\S+\b", string.Empty)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am trying to lowercase all text, but hyperlinks

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I dont have a working regex. That's what I am asking

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I am trying to lowercase all text, but hyperlinks

Comment: Cool, `Regex.Replace(input, @"(https?://\S+\b)|\p{Lu}", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : m.Value.ToLower())`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you actually did it. THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match a hyperlink, and capture it into Group 1, and then just match any uppercase letter to turn its case to lower. Inside a `Regex.Replace` method, implement a match evaluator to check if Group 1 matched, and replace accordingly.

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(https?://\S+\b)|\p{Lu}", 
                m => m.Groups[1].Success ? 
                   m.Groups[1].Value : m.Value.ToLower()
             )
```

The `(https?://\S+\b)` regex is rather rough, there are a lot of URL regex patterns around, choose the one that suits you best.

The `\p{Lu}` matches a single uppercase letter (including all Unicode uppercase letters). If your links cannot start with `HTTP`, you may add a `+` after it (as `\p{Lu}+`) for better performance.